# How can I redirect subdomain.domain.com/* to domain.com/folder/*

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I have to make a redirection on a .htaccess file.

I want to access the content of a folder from a subdomain url like this:

subdomain.domain.com/* => domain.com/folder/*

The folder contains pdf files and I want to acces it with this url for example:

subdomain.domain.com/file.pdf

I'm new into htaccess redirection rules and I'm a little lost.

I tried something like this and test it into https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.domain.com/*$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://domain/folder/ [L,R=301]
```

This code works on the tester but on my website it throws me the error : "The connection was reset".

Do you have any idea on it?

**UPDATE**

Following some advices I try but it doesn't work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com/
RewriteRule (.+\.pdf)$ https://example.com/folder/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.domain.com/*$
> RewriteRule ^(.*) https://domain/folder/ [L,R=301]
> ```

You are not doing anything with the captured URL-path (ie. `(.*)`) so this will always redirect to `https://domain/folder/` (no file).

I would also question whether this should be a 301 (permanent) redirect. Maybe a 302 (temporary) redirect would be preferable here? Note that the 301 is cached, so you will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

It should be like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://domain/folder/$1 [R=302,L]
```

The `$1` backreference contains the URL-path captured in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

The `Host` header (ie. the value of the `HTTP_HOST` server variable) contains the *hostname* only. There is no URL-path component. (Fortunately `/*` matches the slash 0 or more times, so it still "worked" in your testing.)

However, if the folder only contains `.pdf` files then you should be more restrictive and redirect only `.pdf` requests. For example:

```
:
RewriteRule (.+\.pdf)$ https://domain/folder/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @MrWhite for your explanations. So, following your advices I use ```RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com/
RewriteRule (.+\.pdf)$ https://example.com/folder/$1 [R=302,L]``` but it doesn't work anymore...

Comment: @Petitemo There should be no slash (`/`) at the end of the _hostname_ in the `RewriteCond` directive. That will fail to match and the rule won't do anything.